# knowing that kafka has processed all the messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

How to know that Kafka has processed all the messages?
is there any command or log file that species Kafka offset under processing and the last Kafka offset?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command line tool `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to check the consumer lag of your ConsumerGroup. It will show the end offset of the topic the ConsumerGroup is consuming and the last offset the ConsumerGroup committed:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group mygroup
GROUP          TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG       OWNER
mygroup        test-topic      0          5               15              10        xxx
mygroup        test-topic      1          10              15              5         xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it programmatically, e.g. from a Spring application:

```java
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaAdmin admin, ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf) {
    return args -> {
    try (
            AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(admin.getConfig());
            Consumer<String, String> consumer = cf.createConsumer("dummyGroup", "clientId", "");
        ) {
        Collection<ConsumerGroupListing> groups = client.listConsumerGroups()
                .all()
                .get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        groups.forEach(group -> {
            Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> map = null;
            try {
                map = client.listConsumerGroupOffsets(group.groupId())
                        .partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata()
                        .get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = consumer.endOffsets(map.keySet());
            map.forEach((tp, off) -> {
                System.out.println("group: " + group + " tp: " + tp
                        + " current offset: " + off.offset()
                        + " end offset: " + endOffsets.get(tp));
            });
        });
    }
    };
}
```

Comment: this totally works, but individual consumers have lag metrics that are more frequently updated and cheaper to access (and dont require committing offsets back to kafka). 
you would, however, need to "sum" across all consumers in your group somehow,